# Is it possible to get the md5 hash value of a file being downloaded from a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

Is it possible to get the md5 hash value of a file using mongo grid fs being downloaded from a server before storing the file to mongo databse. Now using the code below it stores direcly the data to mongo with the md5 , filename , contenttype etc because I used pipe. Now I want to check the md5 hash of the file first before storing it to the database , I want to get the md5 value of a file first cause i wanna use it to avoid duplicates. Now I did try to log the fileStorage. but i dont think it contains the md5. Any idea? thank you. btw I am using mongo grid fs

## filestorage data

```
GridWriteStream{ 
   _writableState:WritableState{ 
      objectMode:false,
      highWaterMark:16384,
      finalCalled:false,
      needDrain:false,
      ending:false,
      ended:false,
      finished:false,
      destroyed:false,
      decodeStrings:true,
      defaultEncoding:'utf8',
      length:0,
      writing:false,
      corked:0,
      sync:true,
      bufferProcessing:false,
      onwrite:[ 
         Function:         bound onwrite
      ],
      writecb:null,
      writelen:0,
      bufferedRequest:null,
      lastBufferedRequest:null,
      pendingcb:0,
      prefinished:false,
      errorEmitted:false,
      emitClose:true,
      autoDestroy:false,
      bufferedRequestCount:0,
      corkedRequestsFree:{ 
         next:null,
         entry:null,
         finish:[ 
            Function:            bound onCorkedFinish
         ]
      }
   },
   writable:true,
   _events:[ 
      Object:      null prototype
   ]{ 

   },
   _eventsCount:0,
   _maxListeners:undefined,
   _opened:false,
   _opening:true,
   _writable:true,
   _closing:false,
   _destroyed:false,
   _errorEmitted:false,
   _grid:Grid{ 
      db:Db{ 
         _events:[ 
            Object:            null prototype
         ]{ 

         },
         _eventsCount:0,
         _maxListeners:undefined,
         s:[ 
            Object
         ],
         serverConfig:[ 
            Getter
         ],
         bufferMaxEntries:[ 
            Getter
         ],
         databaseName:[ 
            Getter
         ]
      },
      mongo:{ 
[ 
            Function
         ]         MongoError:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Admin:[ 
            Function
         ],
         MongoClient:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Db:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Collection:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Server:[ 
            Function
         ],
         ReplSet:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Mongos:[ 
            Function
         ],
         ReadPreference:[ 
            Function
         ],
         GridStore:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Chunk:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Logger:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Cursor:[ 
            Function
         ],
         GridFSBucket:[ 
            Function
         ],
         CoreServer:[ 
            Function
         ],
         CoreConnection:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Binary:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Code:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Map:[ 
            Function
         ],
         DBRef:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Double:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Int32:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Long:[ 
            Function
         ],
         MinKey:[ 
            Function
         ],
         MaxKey:[ 
            Function
         ],
         ObjectID:[ 
            Function
         ],
         ObjectId:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Symbol:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Timestamp:[ 
            Function
         ],
         Decimal128:[ 
            Function
         ],
         connect:[ 
            Circular
         ],
         instrument:[ 
            Function
         ]
      },
      curCol:'fs'
   },
   options:{ 
      filename:'f9bd6032ceae47a8b8b9be07a5dc839e.jpg',
      data:'1'
   },
   name:'f9bd6032ceae47a8b8b9be07a5dc839e.jpg',
   id:5d9eef3dde7cc73550be84d8,
   mode:'w',
   _store:GridStore{ 
      db:Db{ 
         _events:[ 
            Object:            null prototype
         ]{ 

         },
         _eventsCount:0,
         _maxListeners:undefined,
         s:[ 
            Object
         ],
         serverConfig:[ 
            Getter
         ],
         bufferMaxEntries:[ 
            Getter
         ],
         databaseName:[ 
            Getter
         ]
      },
      referenceBy:1,
      fileId:5d9eef3dde7cc73550be84d8,
      filename:'f9bd6032ceae47a8b8b9be07a5dc839e.jpg',
      mode:'w',
      options:{ 
         filename:'f9bd6032ceae47a8b8b9be07a5dc839e.jpg',
         data:'1'
      },
      isOpen:false,
      root:'fs',
      position:0,
      readPreference:'primary',
      writeConcern:{ 
         w:1
      },
      internalChunkSize:261120,
      promiseLibrary:[ 
         Function:         Promise
      ],
      chunkSize:[ 
         Getter/Setter
      ],
      md5:[ 
         Getter
      ],
      chunkNumber:[ 
         Getter
      ]
   },
   _delayedWrite:null,
   _delayedFlush:null,
   _delayedClose:null
}
```

## Code that downloads the file

```
var download = function (url, dest, filename callback) {

   const file = filename
    const fileStorage = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: file});

    // request.get(url)
                    //     .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
                    //     .pipe(fileStorage)
                    //     .on('close', callback);

};

final_list.forEach(function (str) {
    var filename = str.split('/').pop();

    console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

    download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
});
```

Comment: if the server do not provide trusty md5sum along with the file, you have to do md5sum computationn through the whole file content. In other word ,no,  you  can not get md5 first. To  avoid duplicate and avoid download  twice, you can setup a  temporary storage to place such file, do move or delete after  md5  check

Comment: so you mean i have to download the file first and store it on my server ?

Comment: yes , download and store. unless the server do md5 for you

Comment: for me that is a bad case

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution:
```

[Link for the Read](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Checking-the-MD5-checksum-of-a-Downloaded-File.html)

WINDOWS:

```
1. Download the latest version of WinMD5Free.
2. Extract the downloaded zip and launch the WinMD5.exe file.
3. Click on the Browse button, navigate to the file that you want to check and select it.
4. Just as you select the file, the tool will show you its MD5 checksum.
5. Copy and paste the original MD5 value provided by the developer or the download page.
Click on Verify button.
```

MAC:

```
1. Download the file you want to check and open the download folder in Finder.
2. Open the Terminal, from the Applications / Utilities folder.
3. Type md5 followed by a space. Do not press Enter yet.
4. Drag the downloaded file from the Finder window into the Terminal window.
5. Press Enter and wait a few moments.
6. The MD5 hash of the file is displayed in the Terminal.
7. Open the checksum file provided on the Web page where you downloaded your file from.
8. The file usually has a .cksum extension.

NOTE: The file should contain the MD5 sum of the download file. For example: md5sum: 25d422cc23b44c3bbd7a66c76d52af46
 
9. Compare the MD5 hash in the checksum file to the one displayed in the Terminal.
10. If they are exactly the same, your file was downloaded successfully. Otherwise, download your file again.
```

LINUX:

```
1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type the following command: md5sum [type file name with extension here] [path of the file] -- 
NOTE: You can also drag the file to the terminal window instead of typing the full path.
3. Hit the Enter key.
4. You’ll see the MD5 sum of the file. 
5. Match it against the original value.
```