# How to get a hash or checksum of a file from a stream in node js or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the checksum or the hash of a file from a server without download the whole file to my server or writing it on my disk like reading the data from the server and then getting the hash value.

## Code

```
var download = function (url, dest, callback) {

                request.get(url)
                    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
                    .on('close', callback);

            };

            final_list.forEach(function (str) {
                var filename = str.split('/').pop();

                console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

                download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
            });
```

## hash

```
   function generateChecksum(str, algorithm, encoding) {
        return crypto
            .createHash(algorithm || 'md5')
            .update(str, 'utf8')
            .digest(encoding || 'hex');
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733374/how-to-generate-an-md5-file-hash-in-javascript/33486055#33486055

Comment: @KausUntwale: That’s for browser JavaScript.

Comment: Similar question asked by the OP here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319517/is-it-possible-to-get-the-md5-hash-value-of-a-file-being-downloaded-from-a-serve

Comment: its way far , we are asking for answers or ideas not about similar ones,

Answer (score 1):

Hash objects from Node’s crypto module are writable streams. You can pipe directly to them, something like:

```
request.get(url)
    .pipe(crypto.createHash('md5'))
    .on('readable', function () {
        callback(null, this.read());
    });
```

(Error handling left as an exercise to the reader, because error handling with streams in Node is the absolute worst.)

Comment: How do i log the hashed values ?

Comment: But this reads the entire stream which the OP said they didn't want to do.

Comment: @JhonCaylog: `this.read()` once the Hash has emitted `'readable'` is the hash digest, as a buffer. Try logging `this.read().toString('hex')`, for example.

Comment: @jfriend00: I think “download the whole file to my server” means the same thing as “writing it to my disk” in the question. It’s just impossible otherwise.

Comment: now how are we going to access the data outside so i can use it to query data in mongo ang compare